# Examples of proofs using induction or recursion on a big recursive ordinal

Tags: lo.logic, soft-question, examples, ordinal-numbers, reverse-math

There are many proofs use induction or recursion on $\omega$, or on an arbitary (may be uncountable) ordinal. Are there some good examples of proofs which use a big but computable ordinal?

The original proof of Ramsey theorem and Hales-Jewett theorem use induction on $\omega^2$, but the using is not essential, because Erdos and Shelah have given better bounds by using induction just on $\omega$. And further more $\omega^2$ shouldn't be considered big.

A typical use of big ordinal induction is proving the consistence of axiom systems, for example, using $\varepsilon_0$-induction to prove the consistence of PA. This is one kind of examples.

The existence of Goodstein function uses the induction on $\varepsilon_0$, and I think it's just a directly explaining of how do recursion on ordinal works.

Are there more examples?

Comment: I think that the Robertson-Seymour graph minor theorem is an example. The relevant reference is "The metamathematics of the graph minor theorem" by Friedman, Robertson, and Seymour, in *Logic and Combinatorics* (edited by Stephen Simpson, Amer. Math. Soc. 1987), but unfortunately I don't have a copy of that paper ready to hand.

Comment: @Timothy Chow You can download the paper at this link: http://libgen.is/book/index.php?md5=E1D065356E31DE3477F05FDD64B453A0

Answer (score 4):

This is an expanded version of my comment.  There are examples from wqo (well quasi-order) theory, if you accept that induction on a wqo is "induction on an ordinal" (specifically, the ordinal of the tree of "finite bad sequences" of the wqo).  [Kruskal's tree theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_tree_theorem) can be proved by induction on a certain wqo whose ordinal is bigger than $\Gamma_0$, which is much bigger than the ordinals you mentioned.  This is explained in detail in "What's so special about Kruskal's theorem and the ordinal $\Gamma_0$? A survey of some results in proof theory," by Jean H. Gallier, *Ann. Pure Appl. Logic* **53** (1991), 199–260.

Related to this is Friedman's extension of Kruskal's theorem; let's call it EKT.  In "The metamathematics of the graph minor theorem" by Friedman, Robertson, and Seymour, it is explained that EKT is equivalent (over RCA$_0$) to a weak version of the Graph Minor Theorem that they call the "bounded Graph Minor Theorem," i.e., the Graph Minor Theorem restricted to graphs of bounded tree-width.  The relevant ordinal here is $\alpha_n$, the ordinal of the wqo of graphs of tree-width at most $n$, partially ordered by minor inclusion.

I believe that the exact ordinal corresponding to the full Graph Minor Theorem is still unknown, but is conjectured to exceed $\lim_n \alpha_n$, which is the proof-theoretic ordinal of $\Pi_1^1$-CA$_0$.

Comment: I feel like the proof is simply a *definition* of a WQO, rather than a proof by induction on a WQO. The proof itself is usually in the form of a "minimal bad sequence" argument. I'd also note that it's significantly easier to define and use WQOs and well-founded orders than ordinals, so it might not be quite in the spirit of the question (or maybe it suggests that ordinals are not such useful objects after all...)

Comment: Are this proof of Kruskal's tree theorem uses such a wqo, or it just proves that the trees forms a wqo? And I don't think that means ordinals are not such useful.

Comment: I don't fully understand the distinction that you're trying to draw. The conclusion of Kruskal's tree theorem is that something is a wqo. The "minimal bad sequence" argument is what I'd call an induction argument. I'd call this proof by induction on a wqo, but maybe you reserve that term for a proof that starts with something that is already known to be a wqo, and uses that fact to prove some statement *about* the wqo other than "this is a wqo"? Anyway you can [read the proof](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/1b35/9f6ad805ecc8036ae8610ace368ef9212050.pdf) and decide for yourself.

Comment: The proof of the Kruskal's Tree Theorem itself needn't involve such an induction, but arguably Schmidt's proof that its type (maximum linearization) is $\Gamma_0$ does? This relates to another question I've been wondering about -- I'm a little unclear here on the connection between type on the one hand & proof-theoretic ordinal on the other; I'm not sure how well that's understood actually... but I guess that's not something to start a discussion on in the comments; maybe I should ask that as a separate question here...)

Comment: Hold on, wait -- I just realized we've been talking about the wrong ordinal, right?  Kruskal's tree theorem is small Veblen ordinal, not $\Gamma_0$, right?  May have to go look up this Gallier paper...

Comment: @HarryAltman : Not sure what you mean by the "wrong ordinal." As explained in the paper I mentioned, the validity of induction on $\Gamma_0$ is a natural consequence of Kruskal's theorem. So yes, there is a sense in which Kruskal's theorem is associated with a larger ordinal, but the theorem is also naturally connected with $\Gamma_0$.

Comment: I see!  It's smaller so it makes sense.  Thanks!